# One-word Synonym - 'to narrow down'

Tags: synonyms

> Context: Please **narrow down** your question, which is too broad.

I tried [thesarus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/narrow?s=t) but I doubt those suggested synonyms prevail in use? For example, Google produces only 4 hits for both ['circumscribe your question'](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tighten+your+question%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=iKe1VIHeOMiPyATt24GgBg#safe=off&q=%22circumscribe+your+question%22) and ['tighten your question'](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tighten+your+question%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=iKe1VIHeOMiPyATt24GgBg).

Obiter dictum: I hope that the sample sentence above doesn't apply herein!

Comment: In your example, _sharpen_, _focus_, _tighten_, or _narrow_ would all work. In other instances (as, for example, when the number of options available is too large), _winnow_ can be a useful alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the context, you may find **refine** works, but it's slightly, um, *broader* than **narrow down**.

Answer (score 2):

Just get rid of the "down". It's possible to *[narrow a question](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22narrow%20your%20question%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl)*.

Answer (score 1):

- Please make your question *more specific*
- Please *focus* your question

Comment: Thanks; I forgot to add 'one-word'. Do you know of any 'one-word synonyms'?

Comment: focus is one word.  Also, how about *concentrate*?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, 'focus' is apt. But can you really say 'concentrate your question'?

Comment: @DJFar - 'Concentrate your question' sounds distinctly off-key.